# Google Batch API, multiple authorization headers

Tags: google-api

Looking for some help with the Google Batch API,
got two valid access tokens for two different accounts under the same domain/organization and want to batch two calls, each with it's own authorization header.

If I'm reading into it correctly, it should be possible according to [the API docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch#format-of-a-batch-request):

> The HTTP headers for the outer batch request, except for the Content- headers such as Content-Type, apply to every request in the batch. If you specify a given HTTP header in both the outer request and an individual call, then the individual call header's value overrides the outer batch request header's value. The headers for an individual call apply only to that call.
>
> For example, if you provide an Authorization header for a specific call, then that header applies only to that call. If you provide an Authorization header for the outer request, then that header applies to all of the individual calls unless they override it with Authorization headers of their own.

Testing it out with Postman (POST https://www.googleapis.com/batch)
when the request has no authentication header but the inner request has valid authentication headers:

```
--batch_foobarbaz 
Authorization:Bearer <accesstoken1>
Content-Type: application/http Content-ID: one

GET /gmail/v1/users/me/profile

--batch_foobarbaz 
Authorization:Bearer <accesstoken2>
Content-Type: application/http 
Content-ID: two

GET /gmail/v1/users/me/profile

--batch_foobarbaz--
```

I get as a response "Login Required" for both of the requests:

```
--batch_x-oYQ5TohrI_AAd7PA4mQcg
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: response-one

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sun, 12 Nov 2017 12:28:55 GMT
Expires: Sun, 12 Nov 2017 12:28:55 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 238

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}

--batch_x-oYQ5TohrI_AAd7PA4mQcg
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: response-two

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sun, 12 Nov 2017 12:28:55 GMT
Expires: Sun, 12 Nov 2017 12:28:55 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 238

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}

--batch_x-oYQ5TohrI_AAd7PA4mQcg--
```

As Google commands me, on my second attempt I put an authentication header on the request with "accesstoken1" hoping the inner requests headers would override it:

```
--batch_foobarbaz
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: one
Authorization: Bearer <accesstoken1>

GET /gmail/v1/users/me/profile

--batch_foobarbaz
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: two
Authorization: Bearer <accesstoken2>

GET /gmail/v1/users/me/profile

--batch_foobarbaz--
```

However, the inner Authorization headers gets ignored and I get the same response for both inner requests:

```
--batch_acwJ2jJl7Vk_AAwDDvF7GqQ
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: response-one

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
ETag: "Sa8s0oAMlJSbjHHTmOHVq5KXvZM/ij85zVL5i9x1u7LOtgNBEd-PGZY"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sun, 12 Nov 2017 12:52:16 GMT
Expires: Sun, 12 Nov 2017 12:52:16 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 108

{
 "emailAddress": "user1@whatever.com",
 "messagesTotal": 16,
 "threadsTotal": 13,
 "historyId": "7294"
}

--batch_acwJ2jJl7Vk_AAwDDvF7GqQ
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: response-two

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
ETag: "Sa8s0oAMlJSbjHHTmOHVq5KXvZM/ij85zVL5i9x1u7LOtgNBEd-PGZY"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sun, 12 Nov 2017 12:52:16 GMT
Expires: Sun, 12 Nov 2017 12:52:16 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 108

{
 "emailAddress": "user1@whatever.com",
 "messagesTotal": 16,
 "threadsTotal": 13,
 "historyId": "7294"
}

--batch_acwJ2jJl7Vk_AAwDDvF7GqQ--
```

If anyone can make sense of this I'd be forever grateful

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your inner authentication headers would come after the GET/POST requests.

For example

GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events

Authorization:Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

instead of

Authorization:Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events.

In your example, it would be

--batch_foobarbaz

Content-Type: application/http

Content-ID: one

GET /gmail/v1/users/me/profile

Authorization: Bearer

This worked for me. Let me know if this is working for you.